# What does "Boh!" mean, precisely?

Tags: meaning

I often heard people saying "Boh!" especially, but not only, when I stayed in Rome.

However, I'm unsure what the intended meaning of "Boh!" is, either in Rome or elsewhere. Does it mean *I don't know*, *I don't want to say*, *I'm not interested*, or something else?

Thus, I would like to know what a non-native speaker should deduce when they hear "Boh!"  Please don't answer with "Boh!"

Comment: Boh! is very very common among us Italians, used in a variety of circumstances - as explained above. I tend to use it even among non-native speakers, who in turn look at me with puzzled looks. Then I explain :-) .

Comment: BOH means: I don't know, I don't really care, I don't think anybody should care about it... All at the same time

Comment: @Pejo: Welcome on ItalianSE! Good point of view but could you elaborate more your answer and give more details?

Answer (score 23):

'Boh' means 'I do not know', with all its nuances:

- I don't know,
- I know but I am not gonna tell you,
- I don't know and I don't care,
- I am confused
- etc.

I've been looking around for the etymology of this word but it seems not to be available.

Comment: I'd just stick to plain "I don't know", everything else is speculation IMHO

Comment: I think it's just means I don't know the other translations are not valid

Answer (score 11):

I was watching an Italian movie once, in Italian, with Italian subtitles. If I remember the name of the movie I'll edit this post later. One of the characters said "Boh!" in conversation, and for some reason the subtitles translated it to "Non lo so!"

I feel like the two best translations to English (depending on context) are "Meh" and the humming variant of "I dunno," although I have no idea how to spell that. If you're the speaker you can use it for either/or.

Comment: My first instinct was "Meh" also -- it just sounds as though one is not interested in the outcome or in answering the comment or question!

Answer (score 6):

*Boh* means doubt, indifference, unwillingness to talk about something or to express an opinion. It's widely used in the Roman dialect (but not only). One [possible explanation](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/linteriezione) of its etymology is the sound that one produces when wants to express uncertainty.
A non-native speaker should pay attention to the context, where *Boh!* appears, and then it's quite easy to deduce its meaning, because it usually appears in response to something.

Comment: that *cruscante* didn't think it trough. boh is "the sound that one produces when wants to express uncertainty" only in italy.

Answer (score 4):

*Boh* is used to mean uncertainty, indifference, disbelief, contempt; it is similar to *bah* which is used to express uncertainty, hopelessness, disbelief, contempt, and *mah* that express doubt, uncertainty.

The first two words are onomatopoeic, while *mah* comes from Latin *măgis*.

Comment: “Mah” is simply another way of writing “ma” (possibily to stress the fact that it is being used as an interjection), which is indeed derived from *magis*: http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ma2/

Answer (score 3):

I think that the closest translation in English should be:

> **dunno**

So in formal English is translated as "I don't know".If you analyze some example of `dunno` form [merriam-webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dunno) they can be translated with `boh` :

> “Whatʼre those things?”
> whispered Ron. “Dunno,” said Harry. — J. K. Rowling, Harry Potter and
> the Order of the Phoenix, 2003
>
> Cosa sono quelle cose? bisbigliò Ron. "Boh..." disse Harry

From the [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/boh#Italian)

> Puoi pagare il mio biglietto? Boh, devo vedere se ho i soldi.
>
> Can you pay for my ticket? I don't know, I'll need to check if I have the
> money.

### Any other meaning is purely a conjecture

It's **not** implicit any other meaning like **"I know but I am not gonna tell you"**, **"I don't know and I don't care"**, **"I am confused"**. So if Italians say to you "Boh" usually they not trying to hide you something or avoid answering, they just **don't know**.

Answer (score 1):

I live in Rome. The word "boh" usually is used to say "I don't know". But you have to pay attention in which contest is used. In fact it could be used to say: "I have no idea". This last mean's different from the first cause it is more general.

> -- What time does the match start? 
>   -- Boh (I didn't know it will be a match!)

I hope you will understand! :)
Good bye

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Comment: I don't know if the example provided is actually meaningful. Personally  I never used or heard "boh" used with that meaning.

Answer (score 0):

"Boh" means quite simply "I don't have a clue".

**BUT**

often saying it implies "*Why the heck are you asking me, since there is no reason whatsoever for which I am supposed to know it*"

So, there might be a light intent of reprimand towards the asker when someone says "boh".

Comment: I don't think I agree with this answer. In my experience *boh* is often used without any negative connotation.