# Perché si dice "boh" per esprimere incertezza?

Tags: etymology

In merito al significato dell'interiezione "boh", l'Accademia della Crusca scrive quanto segue:

> "*Boh*" esprime dubbio, indifferenza, reticenza a pronunciarsi su
>   qualcosa; [omissis] sembrerebbe essere semplicemente un'espressione
>   onomatopeica, cioè una trascrizione di un probabile suono che si
>   produce quando si esprime incertezza.
>   (*[Accademia della Crusca](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/printpdf/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/linteriezione)*)

Non mi voglio soffermare sul significato o sull'etimologia di "boh". Piuttosto, *perché gli italiani producono il suono “boh” per esprimere incertezza?**

A titolo di chiarimento, mi rendo conto che i suoni “*mm?*” o “*eh?*”, che gli italiani producono per esprimere incomprensione e di conseguenza domandare chiarimenti, sono prodotti in altre lingue con lo stesso significato (per esempio, francese e inglese). Invece, da quel che mi risulta, il suono “boh” non esiste nella lingua francese e in quella inglese.

Comment: Questa domanda è collegata a [quest'altra](http://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/1142/what-does-boh-mean-precisely): sembra che una chiara spiegazione dell'origine di questa parola non sia facile. Che provenga dal francese ["_bon_"](http://french.about.com/od/expressions/a/bon.htm), "_bene_"? Non lo troverei strano, "bon" è ancora usato in molte zone del Nord Italia. Direttamente dal latino "_bonus_"?

Comment: In inglese si usano [blah](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=blah&defid=1831724), [huh](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Huh&defid=5325441), [buh](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Buh), e tanti altri. Questo fenomeno non è unico per l'italiano, la domanda quindi più o meno significa "e perché esiste l'onomatopea?"

Comment: Non sono sicuro di capire che differenza ci sia tra «l'etimologia di "boh"» e «perché gli italiani producono il suono “boh” per esprimere incertezza?» L'etimo di una parola non dice proprio perché si usa quel suono per esprimere quel concetto?

Comment: Si può chiedere qualsiasi domanda che riguarda l'esistenza delle parole in inglese sugli altri siti di SE: [english.se] oppure [ell.se]