# "I have no idea" in Italian

Tags: translation, idioms, phrase-request

How can I say "I have no idea" in Italian in a very emphatic way? I think I have sometimes heard or read some idiomatic expressions, such as "non ne ho la più pallida idea", but I don't remember them.

Comment: I have no idea !

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE! Please use the "Your answer" form to add an answer to the question posted by the OP.

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE! Your answer seems to be a comment. If you want to comment a question, you can use the "add comment" button under the question itself, once you have gained at least 50 reputation. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://italian.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://italian.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
Non lo so
Non lo so proprio
Non ne ho idea
Non ne ho la più pallida idea
```

In ordine crescente di intensità

Ovviamente `ne` si riferisce a qualcosa che è già stato menzionato, ma immagino che tu lo sappia già. Se vuoi dire:

```
I have no idea what to do in this situation
```

Si possono usare tutti e quattro, allo stesso modo:

```
Non so cosa fare
Non so proprio cosa fare
Non ho idea di cosa fare 
Non ho la più pallida idea di cosa fare
```

Personalmente, trovo la versione con "pallida" un po' trita.

**EDIT**:

```
Bo[ooo]h!
```

come [discusso qui](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/1142/what-does-boh-mean-precisely).

Comment: Anche "non (ne) ho la minima idea".

Comment: O “non saprei (proprio)”.

Comment: Anche "Chissà!"