# Etymology of 'boh'

Tags: etymology

As stated in [this post](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/1144/707), 'boh' means 'I do not know', with all its nuances:

- I don't know
- I know but I am not gonna tell you
- I don't know and I don't care
- I am confused
- ...

I've been looking around for the etymology of this word but it seems not to be available on the Internet.

Is there anyone who knows its etymology?

Comment: Boh! A me sembra che lì non si chieda circa l'etimologia di 'Boh', @dag

Answer (score 6):

You can find an explanation about the etymology of "boh" in this article by the [Accademia della Crusca](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/printpdf/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/linteriezione):

> L'etimologia delle interiezioni («per quanto», come scrive Nencioni nel libro citato, «in questo 
>   settore sia possibile fare dell'etimologia») non è sempre accertata, anche se ci sono casi in 
>   cui essa risulta più chiara; ad esempio l'interiezione *beh* o *bè* è una forma apocopata di *bene*
>   oppure *mah* che altro non è che la congiunzione avversativa *ma* usata in funzione interiettiva 
>   per indicare incertezza, perplessità di fronte a una domanda a cui non si sa rispondere; e 
>   ancora *to'* che è l'imperativo apocopato di *togliere (togli)* nell'accezione arcaica di prendere. 
>   *Boh* esprime dubbio, indifferenza, reticenza a pronunciarsi su qualcosa; è caratteristica, ma 
>   non esclusiva, dell'uso regionale romano, come si ricava da diversi esempi pasoliniani di 
>   *Ragazzi di vita*. Tuttavia, sembrerebbe essere semplicemente un'espressione onomatopeica 
>   (così T. De Mauro nel *Grande Dizionario italiano dell'Uso*, UTET, Torino, 2000), cioè una trascrizione di un probabile suono che si produce quando si esprime incertezza.

That is, the origin of "boh" seems to be onomatopoeic: it's the transcription of a sound used to express uncertainty.

Answer (score 4):

I would not obsess over the etymology of interjections like "boh", "mah", "bah", "tze", "pah".

Unless evidence of the contrary, they *likely* don't have one as such.

It would be interesting to compare them with the facial expression they result in, however, or analyze them from an [ideasthetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideasthesia) point of view - there is probably scholarly research on the matter, although I wouldn't know where to start to look for it.

Comment: I agree, but notice that some interjection may have an actual etymology, as explained in the quotation in Charo's answer, since they are (variations of) actual words, as for instance, among those you mention, *mah*, which is a version of *ma* (“but”), which in turn derives from Latin *magis* (“more”).

Comment: I said "likely" :)
Note that there seems to be some level of disagreement here: according to Nencioni (http://nencioni.sns.it/index.php?id=778) "mah" is simply the conjunction "ma".

Comment: Sorry, Tobia, I am not sure I understand where the disagreement is: aren't we both saying that *mah* is a variant of *ma*? Thanks for the link to Nencioni's works!

Comment: Nevermind, I misread you. Sorry.