# In quale contesto usiamo la parola "Boh" in italiano?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

I watched this short video about the word "Boh" in Italian: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fdi4GKi52as

What is the origin and what is the context in which we use this word?

Grazie mille

Answer (score 2):

You use the word [boh](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/boh/) to express uncertainty, for example when you don’t know an answer to a question.

A similar question [here](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/1142/what-does-boh-mean-precisely)

Comment: And what could be the possible origin of this word? Thank you

Comment: Refer to the @I.M. answer to this question following the link provided at the top, above your question

Comment: Grazie tanto amico!

Comment: @MuhammadMaqsoodurRehman: Si dice "grazie tante" e non "grazie tanto" perché "grazie" e femminile plurale.